# unable to get the XML response using 'Get' request through 'Ruby' language

Tags: ruby, xml, get, net-http

I am not able to get the xml response after triggering 'GET' request using Ruby language.My Current Code is as follows:

```
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'base64'

base_url = '<URL>'
app_guid = '<App GUID Value>'
format = "xml"

# Example using bug.fetch

params = {
  "appGUID" => app_guid,
  "format" => format,
  "method" => "bug.fetch",
  "bugId" => "1234567"
  }

puts "XML Response"

res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(base_url), params)
puts res.body
```

Comment: Please note that i want to make a 'GET' request through an API to 'HTTPS' server.

Comment: Why are you doing a post then?

Answer (score 1):

As Frederick notes, your code is making a `POST` request. If you want to use `GET` do:

```
uri = URI.parse(base_url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

If you still encounter errors, you may wish to use this alternative syntax:

```
uri = URI.parse(base_url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
conn = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
conn.use_ssl = true
res = conn.get uri.request_uri
```